# FTP issue in docker containers

Tags: linux, firewall, ftp, docker, container

To start i'm pretty new on docker engine. I have a little cluster of two servers with docker engine.

On node1 i have: one container with a openvpn a container with a ftp configured with passive mode

container ftp:

```
docker run -d -v /var/lib/docker/volumes/ftpuserdb/_data:/home/vsftpd -p 20:20 -p 21:21 -p 21100-21110:21100-21110 -e FTP_USER=bob -e FTP_PASS=12345 -e PASV_ADDRESS=<PUBLIC IP>  -e PASV_MIN_PORT=21100 -e PASV_MAX_PORT=21110 -e PASV_ADDRESS_ENABLE=YES -e PASV_ENABLE=YES --name ftp-server fauria/vsftpd
```

On node2 i just have a container to test the connection ftp (ftpclient) .

i can connect to the ftp from (ftpclient) , but when i try to use passive-mode, i have an error :

227 Entering Passive Mode (public,ip,from,node1,82,110). ( i hide the ip ^^)

ftp: connect: Connection refused

When i checked the firewall : i can find my port open.

```
Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             IP          udp dpt:openvpn
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             IP           tcp dpt:3000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             IP           tcp dpt:21110
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             IP           tcp dpt:21109
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             IP           tcp dpt:21108
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             IP           tcp dpt:21107
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             IP           tcp dpt:21106
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             IP           tcp dpt:21105
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             IP           tcp dpt:21104
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             IP           tcp dpt:21103
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             IP           tcp dpt:21102
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             IP           tcp dpt:21101
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             IP           tcp dpt:21100
```

But if i try my ftp from my node2 directly from host i have no issue. all works.

Anyone have an idea? i tried lot of thing and can't figure out....

Regards

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol):

> In passive mode, the client uses the control connection to send a PASV command to the server and then receives a server IP address and server port number from the server, which the client then uses to open a data connection from an arbitrary client port to the server IP address and server port number received.

So basically the client can connect to any random port on the FTP server.

Some FTP servers (`proftpd` with the [`PassivePorts` directive](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_PassivePorts.html) for instance) can be told to restrict the ports they use for passive mode to some range that you could [map to the same range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022656/docker-expose-a-range-of-ports) on the host.

Comment: So do you think i can find a workaround?
To me, the mapping is done when i declare my container.

Comment: See edited answer

Comment: OK, but in my case  i used:  -p 21100-21110:21100-21110 who is the key to mapp host port to the container.

SO in my case i have 10 ports mapped and opened on firewall directly in the host. :(

Comment: Yes, and the host maps them to the container, so all hacking is going to the container. And if you didn't do this you would have to leave all the ports open. Active FTP allows a paranoid server to serve trusting clients, passive FTP is for trusting servers and paranoid clients. You can't be paranoid at both ends...